# why angular js should be used over typical jquery web application

Tags: angularjs

I am starting a new web application in angular js.But there is one thing stuck in my mind that why should I use angular js over jquery applications.So please suggest me pros and cons for angular js.

Thanks

Comment: Build something with Angular or number of other MVC based frameworks available out there, and compare it to jquery approach, you will have your answer. Start with http://todomvc.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular JS is a MVC framework, so while creating a complete Web app using Angular is easy as we can have separate view , controller and services.
Using Jquery helps in DOm manipulation, but for having MVC app is nearly impossible using JQ.
Have a look at this url for more details :
[Why to use Angular JS](http://www.jeremyzerr.com/why-you-should-use-angularjs-your-next-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

Angular Js have build in MVC structure . Also it have the following adavantage

Data Binding

Directives

Extensibility

AngularJS is a toolset for building the framework most suited to your application development. It is fully extensible and works well with other libraries. Every feature can be modified or replaced to suit your unique development workflow and feature needs. Read on to find out how.